# Abaqus C++ API syntax

Tags: c++, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I am new to Abaqus C++ API and have question about the syntax.

```
db_Odb& odb = openOdb("file.odb");
odb_Step& step = odb.steps()["Step-1"];

odb_Instance& instance = 
    odb.rootAssembly().instances()["PART-1-1"];
```

There are several instances that the syntax is something like `odb.steps()["Step-1"]`.

My question is in `odb.steps()["Step-1"]`:

- is `odb` an object?
- is `steps()` a method of the object?
- what is `steps()["str"]`? I did not see that in regular C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions: Yes, yes, and index operator. It is all standard C++ syntax.

Without knowing the library in question at all, the class might look something like this:

```cpp
class db_Odb
{
public:
    std::unordered_map< std::string, odb_Step >& steps();
    // ...
};
```

So `odb.steps()` returns an indexable object (here I've used a hash map), and then we look up the key in it by appending `["Step-1"]`, which calls the map's [index operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) and returns a reference to a single `odb_Step` instance in that map.